# Multiple setOnClickListener() calls result in unexpected behavior

Tags: android

I've got a piece of code to set up an `OnClickListener` for several `TextView` objects. However, when I click on one of them, it performs all of the actions associated with all of the other `TextView` objects that appear below it in the list. Code:

```
    TextView wake = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wake);
    TextView ringer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ringer);
    TextView nap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nap);
    TextView camera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    TextView volumes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volumes);
    TextView gallery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);

    wake.setOnClickListener(this);
    ringer.setOnClickListener(this);
    nap.setOnClickListener(this);
    camera.setOnClickListener(this);
    volumes.setOnClickListener(this);
    gallery.setOnClickListener(this);
```

So far, I have the following `Switch - Case` statement in my onClick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent;

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.wake:

    case R.id.ringer:
        setRingerState(true);

    case R.id.nap:

    case R.id.camera:
        intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();

    case R.id.volumes:


    case R.id.gallery:
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
```

Notice that I only have three of them implemented currently. What happens is that if I select the `TextView` for `gallery`, it fires only its associated action. However, if I select `camera`, it launches both itself and the action for gallery. If I choose `ringer`, it will change the ringer state, launch the camera, and the gallery.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I'm setting the same OnClickListener to all of these objects, but do I really have to do something like:

```
    ringer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setRingerState(true);

        }   
    });
```

For each one? It seems so ugly. Do I have any other options or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to break after each case:

```
case R.id.ringer:
  setRingerState(true);
  break;
case R.id.camera:
  intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
  break;
// etc
```

Otherwise the execution just falls through and all of the functions get run.

Comment: Yes, I came to that conclusion just before you responded. Thanks, such a stupid mistake.